# I am trying to execute Kaprekars Constant in python, but I am getting this following error

Tags: python

```
def difficultNumber(num):
    count=0

    while num !=6174:
        num = list(str(num))
        if len(num) < 4:
            while len(num) != 4:
                num.insert(1,'0')

        count +=1

        des = int(''.join(sorted(str(num), reverse=True)))
        asc = int(''.join(sorted(str(num))))
        result = int(des) - int(asc)
    return count
print(difficultNumber(input()))
```

===========================

```
8786

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cb_ex9.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(difficultNumber(input()))
  File "cb_ex9.py", line 12, in difficultNumber
    des = int(''.join(sorted(str(num), reverse=True)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "][8876,,,''''''''   "
```

Comment: Follow this ready-made guide on [Kaprekar's constant in Python](https://ao.ms/how-many-times-to-kaprekars-constant-using-python/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're using the variable `num` to represent two things: either a number, or a list of 1-element strings containing the digits that make up the number, and are having difficulty keeping track of which of these two things `num` is all the way through your program.

The body of your outer `while` loop starts by converting `num` as a number to `num` as a list of digit strings, and then makes the number up to four digits by inserting zero digits at the front.  So far so good.  You then compute `des` and `asc` using the following code

```
        des = int(''.join(sorted(str(num), reverse=True)))
        asc = int(''.join(sorted(str(num))))
```

It seems you have forgotten `num` is now a list of strings.  When you call `str` on `num`, you are calling `str` on the list `['8', '7', '8', '6']`, and hence you end up with the string `"['8', '7', '8', '6']"`.  Sorting the characters of that string in reverse order gives you the string `"][8876,,,''''''''   "`, which of course cannot be converted to a number, hence the error you get.

So, let's remove the call to `str` from the calculations of `des` and `asc`:

```
        des = int(''.join(sorted(num, reverse=True)))
        asc = int(''.join(sorted(num)))
```

What happens when we run your program now?  We get the same error!

At this point we need to be careful not to simply dismiss this change as having had no effect.  It has; it just doesn't look like it has.  We can prove that it has had an effect by `print`ing the value of the `count` variable after incrementing it: before, it only printed `1`, now it prints `1` and `2`.  Now we are getting into the second iteration of the `while` loop; before we were failing in the first.

But why are we still getting the same error?

At the start of the `while` loop, we call `num = list(str(num))`.  Assuming `num` is an `int`, this converts `num` to a list of digits.  However, at the end of the `while` loop, `num` isn't converted back to an `int`.  It's still a list of digits.  The next time through the `while` loop we end up calling `str` on a list again.  But why wasn't `num` converted back to an `int` at the end of the `while` loop?  Because the difference between `des` and `asc` was assigned to `result`, *but nothing is done with the value in* `result`.  You've performed a calculation and then ignored the result of it.

I'm guessing that instead of writing

```
        result = int(des) - int(asc)
```

you meant to write

```
        num = int(des) - int(asc)
```

Making this change fixes your code and it appears to work as you would expect.  Enter `8786` and it prints `3`.

I would recommend to you that you go back through your code and introduce a second variable, named `numDigits` or `digitsOfNum` for example, and use this instead of `num` when you are working with a list of digits.  That way your code should hopefully be easier for you to understand.  You might also want to think about what happens if someone enters a number longer than four digits (e.g. `123456`), or contains the same digit repeated four times, e.g. `5555`.

Comment: @GuarangPatel Please either accept this answer or explain why it's incorrect

Comment: Thanks! removing 'str' from dsc and asc worked. Since I have converted the string into 'int' twice, I guess no need to change result = int(des) - int(asc) to num = int(des) - int(asc). Thank you so Much @Luke Woodward.